# Vertical shoot em up from early 80s

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking to identify a vertical shooter from the 80s.

The setting is futuristic, with the main ship being able to get upgrades based on the floating bonus which is a letter. One of the was a flamethrower, another was a six shooter. When taking the letter, parts were combined into the ship to give the upgrade. The letter "P" would give an extra life, unless it was a brown colored "P" which would instead instantly kill you.

The first boss was a ship with some sort of long "tentacles" made of circles sprites.

I played it around 1982 or something like that.

EDIT: it was an arcade game that I used to play in a pizzeria near my house. It was way before the time of Xenon 2, the next year my parents bought me a ZX spectrum 16K

Comment: Could it have been Xenon 2? On which platform, was there music or sound effects?

Comment: Arcade? Console? Home computer?

Comment: @alan b sorry, please see my edit

Comment: *Terra Cresta* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Cresta) comes to mind for the ship upgrades, but I don't remember the boss having tentacles made of circle sprites - but then I was never very good at tyhe game.  It's from 1985, but it's a sequel to *Moon Cresta* from 1980,

Comment: I know terra cresta very well (the phoenix is easy to remember) , it was a completely different game unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little later than 1982 but I think this is SNK's ['Alpha Mission'](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/ASO:_Armored_Scrum_Object/Tile_items), also known as 'ASO : Armored Scrum Object'.

It has standard pickups for power-ups but also brown versions which are 'power downs'. The ship has various armour sets that you can switch between, changing the appearance. The stage 1 boss is a round sprite tentacle affair.

Comment: Very nice find!   There is even a 'P' extra life powerup, and brown ones are de-powerups.   No mention of a brown P that kills you, but that could be a misrememberence.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I had the year wrong (by 3 years, but that's a lot in videogames). Thanks a lot for this 